# C- Strange warnings from codeblocks

Tags: c, codeblocks, extern

When i compile and run the following code, codeblocks(windows 7 64-bit) issues a couple of warnings:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
extern int i=10;     //Warning

int main()
   {
       extern int i;
       printf("%d\n",i);
   }

int i;
```

The warnings are as follows:-

*Line 3: warning: 'i' initialized and declared 'extern' [enabled by default]*

Any explanation for this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken the help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268589/warning-in-extern-declaration/4268620#4268620)

Thats a valid syntax. The problem is that `extern` keyword is redundant because the object is initialised in the same compilation unit.

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem,in fact, it makes it even worse.

Comment: Please refer to this-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348700/doubt-related-to-extern-keyword-usage

Comment: @BradLarson:- But since I have updated my answer I didnt attributed that!!!

Answer (score 1):

That's normal, « extern i ; » means « Okay, there is a variable i somewhere in another file (already initialized). », and you try to affect to it a new value!

I think you should have a look at the « extern » key word.